# How to close a session in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

Hi I created suit tests for my api, but when running the robot file my server stops at some point with the error:

```
 http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:8000: accept: too many open files; retrying in 5ms
```

This is because robot is creating session using `Create Session` keyword but is not closing it
how can I close a session after I finish using it?
thank you

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using the keyword `Delete All Sessions`